# Integrating $ \int_{\lambda} \frac{z^s}{1 - e^z} dz $ along negative real axis with different parameterisations leads to contradictory results

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to integrate $$ \int_{\lambda} \frac{z^s}{1 - e^z} dz $$ along the negative real axis where $ z $ takes the path from $ -1 $ to $ -\infty $. I solve it in two different ways.

Taking the parameterization $ z = -r = re^{-i \pi} $ where $ r $ varies from $ 1 $ to $ \infty $:

$$ \int_{\lambda} \frac{z^s}{1 - e^z} dz
= \int_1^\infty - \frac{r^s e^{-i \pi s}}{1 - e^{-r}} dr
= - e^{-i \pi s} \int_1^\infty \frac{r^s}{1 - e^{-r}} dr
$$

Taking the parameterization $ z = -r = re^{i \pi} $ where $ r $ varies from $ 1 $ to $ \infty $:

$$ \int_{\lambda} \frac{z^s}{1 - e^z} dz
= \int_1^\infty - \frac{r^s e^{i \pi s}}{1 - e^{-r}} dr
= - e^{i \pi s} \int_1^\infty \frac{r^s}{1 - e^{-r}} dr
$$

Why do the two parameterizations lead to different results even though both parameterizations use $ z = -r $? Which one would be considered the correct result for my integral and why? What is the blunder I am making in the parameterization that leads to the incorrect result?

Comment: What is $s$ and how do you define $z^{s}$ for $z <0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $ s $ is a complex number and $ z^s  = e^{s \log z} $.

Comment: $\log z $ has infinitely many values. Have you studied some Complex Analysis? If not you should completely avoid fractional powers of a  negative number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In comments, you mention that you have defined $z^s=e^{s\log(z)}$. To do this, you must choose a branch of $\log$ and use it consistently. Note that $z=-r=re^{i\pi}=re^{-i\pi}$ are all the same number. However, you are using two values for $\log(z)$: $\log(r)+i\pi$ and $\log(r)-i\pi$ when you say $z^s=r^se^{i\pi s}$ and $z^s=r^se^{-i\pi s}$. These are values of $\log(z)$ from two *different* branches of $\log$.

This means you are not simply reparameterizing, but actually changing the path.

One has to handle non-integer powers of non-positive numbers with care.